# Ruby on rails error rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, syntax-error

Whenever I run rake `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` it returns with a syntax error

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-  2.2.1@rails3tutorial/rails_projects/first_app/db/migrate/20150825050353_create_u    sers.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport- 4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in `load_migration'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:769:in `migration'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1047:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1039:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `block in migrate'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in `each'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in `migrate'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:819:in `up'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `migrate'
/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
 /Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I checked everything and all it returns with is

```
"20150825050353_create_users.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end,  expecting end-of-input"


 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
      t.string  "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string  "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string  "password", :limit => 40
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: paste the full code of your `20150825050353_create_users.rb` file. You have a syntax error there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
t.timestamps null: false
```

To:

```
t.timestamps :null => false
```

Comment: that returns with another error== 20150825065823 AlterUsers: migrating =======================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users.broken")
   -> 0.0017s
-- add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, {:limit=>25, :after=>"email"})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: admin_users: ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ADD "username" varchar(25)/Users/IsaiahxD/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

Comment: That's a different error in a different file. So, my answer solved the issue with your `20150825050353_create_users.rb` file. Now, looking at your new error, `no such table: admin_users` you don't have that table in your database but your migration is trying to reference that.

Comment: You need to make sure you have `admin_users`  table in your database.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam please join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88338/ror

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciated it